# Как дождаться выполнения нескольких Promise аналогично Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

Promise.all возвращает промис, который отклоняется при отклонении любого из переданных all обещаний. Например следующий код:

```js
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("resolve 1");
    resolve(1);
  }, 2000);
});

const b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("reject 2");
    reject(2);
  }, 1000);
});

const c = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("resolve");
  resolve(3);
});

Promise.all([a, b, c]).then(
  r => {
    console.log(r);
  },
  () => {
    console.log("err");
  },
);
```

выведет

```
resolve 3
reject 2
err
resolve 1
```

т.е. все завершилось без ожидания завершения промиса a (**resolve 1** выводится после **err**). Вопрос в том, как дождаться, пока все промисы будут выполнены и/или отклонены?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень просто: замаскировать ошибку через вызов `catch`.

```js
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("resolve 1");
    resolve(1);
  }, 2000);
});

const b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("reject 2");
    reject(2);
  }, 1000);
});

const c = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("resolve 3");
  resolve(3);
});

Promise.all([a, b, c].map(p => p.catch(x => console.error(x)))).then(
  r => {
    console.log(r);
  }
);
```

Результат: [1, undefined, 3].

Comment: Ошибка теряется.

Comment: @Qwertiy так лучше?

Comment: Ну обычно с ошибкой надо что-то делать, а не на консоль выводить) Я в своём ответе постарался её в коллбэк прокинуть.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("resolve 1");
    resolve(1);
  }, 2000);
});

const b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("reject 2");
    reject(2);
  }, 1000);
});

const c = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("resolve");
  resolve(3);
});

Promise.all([a, b, c].map(p => p.then(
  x => ({ resolved: x }),
  e => ({ rejected: e })
))).then(results => {
  console.log('=== ALL ===');
  
  for (var res of results) {
    if ('resolved' in res) { // Not res.resolved because `resolve(0)`
      console.log(res.resolved);
    } else {
      console.log('error', res.rejected);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот как-то так получилось (не знаю на сколько это говнокод), я сделал функцию, которая модифицирует промисы, добавляя им свойство `isPending`, в методе `waitForAll` я каждому промису добавляю обработчики в `then`, в которых при успешном/неуспешном выполнени промиса пробегаю входной массив и проверяю, у всех ли промисов в масиве `isPending == false`, если так, значит все промисы уже завершились.

```js
const a = MakePromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("resolve 1");
    resolve(1);
  }, 2000);
}));

const b = MakePromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("reject 2");
    reject(2);
  }, 1000);
}));

const c = MakePromise(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("resolve");
  resolve(3);
}));

waitForAll([a, b, c]);

function waitForAll(arr) {
  arr.forEach((p) => {
    p.then(
      (r) => {
        if (allDone(arr)) console.log('all done');
      },
      (e) => {
        if (allDone(arr)) console.log('all done');
      });
  });
};

function allDone(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].isPending()) return false;
  }
  return true;
};

function MakePromise(promise) {
  var isPending = true;

  var result = promise.then(
    (v) => {
      isPending = false;
      return v;
    },
    (e) => {
      isPending = false;
      throw e;
    }
  );

  result.isPending = () => {
    return isPending;
  };
  return result;
}
```

Я понял что предыдущий вариант явно не очень, сделал через каунтер, тоесть функция `waitForAll` получает массив промисов, сразу записываем в переменную длину массива (количество промисов) и в обработчиках `then` уменьшаем ету переменную ну и сравниваем ее с `0`, тоесть если количество 0, значит все промисы выполнены :

```js
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("resolve 1");
    resolve(1);
  }, 2000);
});

const b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("reject 2");
    reject(2);
  }, 1000);
});

const c = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("resolve");
  resolve(3);
});

waitForAll([a, b, c]);

function waitForAll(arr) {
  var count = arr.length;
  arr.forEach((p) => {
    p.then(
      (r) => {
        count--;
        if (count == 0) console.log('all done');
      },
      (e) => {
        count--;
        if (count == 0) console.log('all done');
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: Спасибо за идеи.